# polynomial algebras and their coefficients in prime fields

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, finite-fields

According to the definition of the polynomial algebras $A(n)$ and $A(n,m)$ for $ n \in \mathbb {N} $ and $ m \in \mathbb {N}^n$, if $\mathbb{F}$ be field $GF(2)$ and $ X_1,...,X_n$ be $n$ pairwise commuting indeterminates over GF(2), then for $a\in \mathbb{N}$ we write $ X^a$  for $ X_1 ^ {a_1}...X_n^{a_n}$. Now $A(n)$ denote the comutative algbera consisting all formal sums over GF(2) with the form $\sum_{a\in\mathbb{N} } \alpha_a X^a$ equipped with the usual addition and the multiplication $ (\sum _a \alpha _a X^a) ( \sum _b \beta _b X^b)= \sum_c (\sum_{a+b=c} \alpha _a \beta_b {c \choose a}) X^c$, where the multi-binomial coefficient is evaluated modulo $2$ and thus is considered as an element in the prime field. 
I need help of you to explain more about "multi-binomial coefficient which is evaluated modulo $2$" ? Can anyone please help me to understand this evaluation through examples? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My educated guess as to the meaning of this product rule is the following. The product of
two monomials like
$$
P=X_1^{a_1}X_2^{a_2}\cdots X_n^{a_n}\qquad\text{and}\qquad 
Q=X_1^{b_1}X_2^{b_2}\cdots X_n^{b_n}
$$
is defined to be
$$
P\cdot Q=\left(\prod_{i=1}^n\binom{a_i+b_i}{a_i}\right)
X_1^{a_1+b_i}X_2^{a_2+b_2}\cdots X_n^{a_n+b_n},
$$
where the binomial coefficients are calculated modulo two. This rule is then extended linearly to all polynomials.

[Lucas' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem) is the key to understanding the binomials modulo two. The binomial coefficient $\binom n k$ is an odd integer, if and only if in base two expansions $n$ has a $1$ whenever $k$ does. Otherwise the binomial coefficient is even, and thus zero modulo two.

So for example
$$
X_1^1\cdot X_1^1= 0,
$$
because $\binom{1+1}1=2\equiv0$, but
$$
X_1^2\cdot X_1^1=X_1^3,
$$
because $\binom{2+1}1=3\equiv1$.

Because $13=8+4+1=1101_2$ in base two, you get that
$$
X_1^aX_1^{13-a}=X_1^{13},
$$
if $a$ is one of $0=0000_2$, $1=0001_2$, $4=0100_2$, $5=0101_2$, $8=1000_2$, $9=1001_2$,
$12=1100_2$ or $13=1101_2$. Because the second bit from the right of $13$ is equal to $0$, the binomial coeffcient $\binom{13}a$ is, by Lucas, an even number, whenever that bit is $1$ in base-2 representation of $a$. That is the case for all $a\in\{2,3,6,7,10,11\}$.
Check this from Pascal's triangle. It is kinda neat!

The different variables then seem to play independently from each other. So for example
$$X_1^4X_2^3 \cdot X_1^3 X_2^8=X_1^7X_2^{11},$$
because both $\binom 73$ and $\binom {11}8$ are odd, but
$$
X_1^4X_2^3 \cdot X_1^3 X_2^2=0\cdot X_1^7X_2^5=0,
$$
because $\binom 52=10$ is even.

---

Educated as it may be this was still a guess.

---

This looks vaguely familiar though. In my distant youth I played with rings a bit like this (something like rings of differential operators reduced modulo a prime number, here $p=2$) - the "powers" of a generator were multiplied like these. The way I thought about them (naturally coming from the characteristic zero structures) was as follows. Think of $X_i^{a_i}$ as $T_i^{a_i}/(a_i!)$, where $T_i$ is a "normal" indeterminate, so $T_i^{a_i}$ was the usual product of $a_i$ copies of $T_i$. Given this, we get
$$
X_i^{a_i}\cdot X_i^{b_i}=\frac{T_i^{a_i}}{a_i!}\frac{T_i^{b_i}}{b_i!}=
\frac{T_i^{a_i+b_i}}{a_i! b_i!}=\binom{a_i+b_i}{a_i}X_i^{a_i+b_i}.
$$
For the algebra to work out correctly in characteristic $p$ I needed to play with combinations of $X_i^{a_i}$ instead of $T_i^{a_i}$.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I think in yoour example $ X_1^2.X_1^2 = X_1^3$ the second $X_1$ must have power 1 , right?

Comment: and also for $X_1^4X_2^3 \cdot X_1^3 X_2^2$ we have $ 7 \choose 4$ for the coefficient of $X_1$ , instead of $7\choose 3$, due to the definition?

Comment: and one more question is that when we say that "the binomial coefficient is even", it means that in the commutative algebra $A(n)$ we do not have terms with those coefficients, in the other word they are zero and we only have odd coefficients?

Comment: A) Correct. I meant $X_1^2\cdot X_1^1$. B) $\binom 73=\binom 74$ because always $\binom n k=\binom n {n-k}$, so it doesn't matter. C) Technically I possibly should have used $m\cdot 1_A$ in place of $m$ for all integers $m$. This is a common way of thinking of integers as elements of any algebra. And, correct, it amounts to reducing $m$ modulo the characteristic of the base field.